# Can Python choose a value from pivot table field and that pivot table is from an existing connection

Tags: python, excel, automation

I am using xlwings to control excel in Python, and that excel sheet has a pivot table field. that pivottable field is from an existing connection.

[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttk3u.png)

```
Sheet=Wb.sheets[1]

Sheet.range('B4').value
Out[25]: '10/28/2020'

Sheet.range('B4').value  = '10/29/2020' (***Note: this is not working***)
```

currently it shows 10/28/2020, I can manually change it to 10/29/2020 just from that dropdown box. the question is how do I use python to change it from 10/28/2020 to 10/29/2020?

any suggestions? any other python library could be this work?

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to modify pivot tables
I created a macro in excel and replicated the code in python.

```
sheet = "your_sheet"
pivotTableName = "pivot_table_name"
data = "your_field"
value = "10/29/2020"

sht = Wb.sheets[sheet].select()

pivotTable = Wb.api.ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName)
filter_ = pivotTable.PivotFields(data)
filter_.CurrentPage = "(All)"
for f in filter_.PivotItems():
    f.Visible = f.Name == value
```

The code is made to run on the RPA Rocketbot but you can get an idea by checking the module repository
https://github.com/rocketbot-cl/PivotTableExcel

I leaned on the microsoft doc too

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable